Translation or equivalent feature to using an pronoun to highlight interest like with the French « arrête-moi ça » in colloquial speech?

– [Annoying behavior]
– Arrête ça ! [Stop that!]
– [Annoying behavior, again]
– Arrête-moi ça !

In French a pronoun can be used in colloquial speech to highlight the interest or importance of the action for the speaker; it serves no semantic function (this is not like "give me your hand" [donne-moi ta main] i.e. give your hand to me, although it is sometimes constructed using this pattern with the imperative mood and the first-person pronoun). It is not equivalent to starting the phrase with "you there..." or ending it with "there", "now" or "for me".
In the example I provided, you can see it being used only the second time the speaker reacts to the behaviour. If you had to translate this to English or provide an equivalent feature, how would you proceed?

Can you explain the difference between this and all the phrases or structures you say it doesn't match ("You", "now", "for me", etc)? Is it something that can only be used when you repeat a command? (Otherwise, saying it more loudly or using the person's full name or a hundred other techniques might apply.)

@StuartF I might expand when I have a bit more time, but generally I can use equivalent words in French to those I said don't match (Toi là, là, maintenant, pour moi). But no, it is not only used when repeating a command (see examples in linked material). Saying something more loudly and using a person's full name is something I can do in French too, so I hear you but at the same time it is no a similar feature in terms of being at the same level of where this feature works if you get my meaning. It may be impossible to reproduce, so I'd settle for translation using other means (register).

'Stop that, I say!' Beyond this, gets too open-ended, a request for writing advice.

« Arrête ça, que je te dis ». I mean, I don't need writing advice, I was trying to figure out if there was an equivalent feature, outside other features that exist in both languages, I'm interested with how people would translate this and how they approach this. Which is why I chose a very simple example that even someone who knows extremely little about French can parse. Often in cases where I can't translate 1:1, the scope of the change required touches on another level of the language, I need to reformat, change word order, express entirely differently. I'm just curious.

The English version of your conversation sounds like a teacher to a misbehaving student. It would not be used with a stranger on a train.
The closest English equivalent I am aware of would be

– [Annoying behavior]
– Stop that!
– [Annoying behavior, again]
– I said, stop it!

It's not quite the same, as it doesn't express the sense you mentioned of the speaker being personally interested. It may express annoyance at being ignored the first time.
A closer English construction showing personal interest would be

– Stop it, for me!

However this has a sense of pleading rather than of giving an instruction.

Perhaps the English are slightly less peremptory than the French.  At least, the peremptory bit is expressed either as a mixed imperative and interrogative ("Stop that, will you!?") or just as the question "Will you stop that?!"

– Arrête ça ! [Stop that!]
– [Annoying behavior, again]
– Arrête-moi ça !
Can be many things depending on the actual context:

Stop or quit doing that! [arrêter de faire cela]
Stop driving me crazy! [arrêter de me rendre fou]
Turn that [thing] off! [arrêter une machine]
Quit your whining! [arrêter de pleurnicher]

Speech happens in contexts not in the void. However, in English there isn't any colloquial marker as with the French pronoun moi in arrête-moi followed by ça.
I would proceed to find what the speaker is asking be stopped and then in English would look for the right verb to fit that context.
One could also do this:
You stop that now!

Dver show yourself. Do you dare? :)
